# How to fix Error: Whenever I type something in terminal there is an error

Tags: bash, fish

I use fish as my login terminal. I was trying to run android simulator. I already edited my bash profile so I switched to bash by typing bash. I restarted my terminal after I logged off my computer and whenever I type anything I get an error.

Command: cd Desktop/

Response:

```
fish: Unknown command: __fish_pwd
/usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish (line 1):
__fish_pwd
^
in command substitution
    called on line 4 of file /usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish
in function 'fish_title' with arguments 'cd\ Desktop/'
in command substitution
/usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish: Unknown error while evaluating command substitution
in function 'fish_title' with arguments 'cd\ Desktop/'
in command substitution
fish: Unknown command: basename
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish (line 1):
basename (prompt_pwd)
^
in command substitution
    called on line 74 of file ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish
in function 'fish_prompt'
in command substitution
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish: Unknown error while evaluating command substitution
in function 'fish_prompt'
in command substitution
fish: Unknown command: __fish_pwd
/usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish (line 1):
__fish_pwd
^
in command substitution
    called on line 4 of file /usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish
in function 'fish_title'
in command substitution
/usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish: Unknown error while evaluating command substitution
in function 'fish_title'
in command substitution
```

I would like to go back to Fish login shell with no errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `fish` is not a terminal but a shell. Does "I use fish as my terminal." mean that you configured `fish` as your login shell? What exactly means "I typed bash, restarted my terminal"? Please [edit] your question and add clarification and more details.

Comment: You are using a Bash shell with a Fish profile. You need to source a Bash profile. The errors happen every time it tries to put up a prompt. `in function **'fish_prompt'**
in command substitution ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish: Unknown error while evaluating command substitution`

Comment: I have edited my question. I hope that it is clear now.

Comment: Not being able to find `basename` is more troubling. What does `type fish_prompt` show. you?

Comment: type fish_prompt
fish: Unknown command: __fish_pwd
/usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish (line 1): 
__fish_pwd
^
in command substitution
        called on line 4 of file /usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish
in function 'fish_title' with arguments 'type\ fish_prompt'
in command substitution
/usr/local/share/fish/functions/fish_title.fish: Unknown error while evaluating command substitution
in function 'fish_title' with arguments 'type\ fish_prompt'
in command substitution
fish_prompt is a function with definition
# Defined in ...

Comment: I think we need more details. Was fish working normally until you started using android simulator? If so what changed in your fish configuration at that time?

Comment: Fish was working normally before starting android simulator. I typed bash, got the bash shell, restarted my terminal and then errors when I went back to fish.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, your `fish_title` function can't find the function for `__fish_pwd`. It's a strange little function:

```
$ type __fish_pwd
__fish_pwd is a function with definition
# Defined in /usr/local/Cellar/fish/3.1.2/share/fish/functions/__fish_pwd.fish @ line 7
function __fish_pwd --description 'Show current path'
            pwd
end
```

You can always add that to your own ~/.config/fish/functions/ directory.

Comment: I added that to the functions directory. Now when I typed fish from the bash shell I get Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type `help` for instructions on how to use fish
fish: Unknown command: basename
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish (line 1): 
basename (prompt_pwd)
^
in command substitution
        called on line 74 of file ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish
in function 'fish_prompt'
in command substitution
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish: Unknown error while evaluating command substitution
in function 'fish_prompt'
in command substitution